# How many DeLoreans were there in 1955?

Tags: back-to-the-future

In *Back to the Future*, we see Doc and Marty repeatedly returning to 1955. But they weren't the only ones. Biff meets his younger self, and a DeLorean waits hidden in a cave.

So am I correct in counting *four* DeLoreans at most?

1. The one from 1985, driven by Marty. Thid is the one we see in the first film. It goes back to 1985.
2. The one from 2015, driven by Biff. It goes back to 2015.
3. The one from the alternate 1985, driven by Doc and Marty. It disappears to 1885 with Doc.
4. The one from 1885, mothballed by Doc, is waiting hidden in a cave. Marty drives it back to 1885, then back to 1985.

Comment: Are you including the cartoon series and the comic-books, because if so, then dozens.

Comment: The question has been answered there.

Comment: Unbelievable. I went through all the [tag:back-to-the-future] questions, but missed that one.